# Is it possible to select pandas dataframe with row indices and column names?

Tags: python, pandas

For datasets with meaningless row indices, I found it more useful to select data by row numbers but at the same time using column names. I know `.iloc` only takes in row/column numbers (integers) and `.loc` only takes in names. But is there a workaround to do a combination of row number and column name at the same time?

```
    A   B
1   1   a
5   2   a
6   3   a
4   4   b
9   5   b
3   6   b
```

For example, I would like to select the entry at row 2 and column B - I do not necessarily know that row 2 has row name 5 nor column B is the second column. What's the best way to reference that cell then?

(The row names are usually a filtered result or a random sample of a bigger dataset)

Comment: Sorry are you after `df['B'].iloc[2]`?

Comment: would re-indexing help you in this case?

Comment: You could do `df[df.columns[1].iloc[2]` the problem is that using integers for both columns and row labels can become ambiguous

Comment: @EdChum Thanks! I think `df['B'].iloc[2]` is probably the solution to go to, though do you know if this kind of chain indexing is problematic in the same sense as marked [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)?

Comment: @MaxU, re-indexing is what I am currently doing as I could not figure out a way to solve this problem. Just wonder if there is an easier solution so I don't need to re-index every time.

Comment: It's not chain indexing, you're specifically accessing the 3rd row for that series, if you did `df.iloc[2]['B']` then this would be chain indexing

Comment: Why would just a switch of position make the latter a chain indexing? Does this mean that `.iloc` should always come last?

Comment: For datasets with meaningless row indices, why not just throw the row indices away with `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use faster [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) as [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print df
    A  B
1   1  a
5   2  a
6   3  c
8   4  b
9   5  b
10  6  b

print df['B'].iat[2]
c

print df['B'].iloc[2]
c
```

**Timing**:

```
In [266]: %timeit df['B'].iat[2]
The slowest run took 31.55 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.28 µs per loop

In [267]: %timeit df['B'].iloc[2]
The slowest run took 24.47 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael! I think this should be the solution, though I happened to read about "chained indexing" [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy). The example applies to multilevel indexing, but I am not sure if there is also any side effect here?

Comment: I think it is no problem. Btw, if this situtation get in your code, `pandas` raise `warning`.